# $\kappa$-dense ideals on successor $\kappa$

Tags: set-theory

Woodin gave a consistency proof of a normal $\omega_1$-dense ideal on $\omega_1$ from an almost-huge cardinal.  He never published this argument, but it is written up by Foreman in the Handbook of Set Theory.  In this article, and in a paper from the 90s, Foreman claims that this argument is adaptable to other cardinals to yield the consistency of an $\kappa$-dense ideal on $\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is the successor of a regular cardinal.  I have had great trouble trying to prove this claim, as one crucial part of the argument seems specific to $\omega_1$ (which I will explain if you ask).  So does anyone know how to prove Foreman's claim?

Comment: What is the crucial dependence on $\omega_1$? I'm looking at Foreman's article right now, and I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: Look at the paragraph that starts with the following:" We let W be the model V1[G0] and construct the partial ordering C ∈ W as in Lemma 7.61. In V1[G ∗ C], the cardinality of P (C)W is countable, so we can build a W -generic object for C." What are we supposed to do at higher cardinals? Let's say we try for ω2. The analogous forcing C for amalgamating small Levy generics is not countably closed, so how do we build a generic for it in the appropriate model?


Comment: What about $|C|$-strategically closure?

Comment: Eran, that would be good, but how would you show it?

Answer (score 4):

This is answered in chapter 2 of my [thesis](http://www.math.uci.edu/~meskew/thesis.pdf).  As far as I know, this is essentially the only method for obtaining such ideals.  I am very interested in finding alternative constructions.  Please contact me if you have some ideas.